# Using checkboxes to render selected items to <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a populated table of JSON data with a checkbox next to each---I want it so that when a checkbox is selected it pushes that selected item into an array (in this case the div `myFave.hs-gc-header`).

When I `console.log(arr)` it just shows a bunch of empty arrays (I believe one for each of the list items). Not sure why this is--if anyone could shed light on this that would be great.

I think the problem lies with the `populateArr()` block, but I can't say for sure.

#### JS:

```
loadTableData() {
  let tableRes = redactedName.d.results.filter(function(val) {
    return (val.FileLeafRef.trim().length > 0);
  }).map(function(obj) {
    return {
      // "FileName": obj.FileLeafRef,
      // "Path": obj.EncodedAbsUrl,
      "Titles": obj.File.Name
    }
  });

  let allTitles = tableRes;

  for (var i = 0; i < allTitles.length; i++) {
    let tr = $("<tr/>");
    $(tr).append("<td>&nbsp;</td>");
    $(tr).append("<td>" + allTitles[i].Titles + "</td>");
    $(tr).append("<input type='checkbox'/>").addClass("checkbox").val("val");

    /* ---------- */

    function populateArr() {
      let arr = [];
      $(".checkbox input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function() {
        arr.push($(this).val());
      });
      return arr;
    }

    $("#myFave.hs-gc-header").click(function() {
      populateArr();
    })
  };
```

#### HTML snippet

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="description here">
    <meta name="keywords" content="keywords,here">
    <!------------------------------->
    <script 
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/core-js/2.6.2/core.min.js"></script>
    <script 
      type="text/javascript" 
      src="dist/js/jquery_wrapper.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="./bundle.js"></script>

    <div class="km-div-container">
      <div class="col-md-2"> <!-- Left -->
          <div class="form-group">
              <input 
                type="search" 
                class="form-control" 
                id="searchbar" 
                placeholder="Search All Documents...">
          </div>

          <div id="myFave.hs-gc-header">
            <p>My Favorites:</p>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- km -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does `tableRes` look like?

Comment: Hey, I just added it

Comment: Please include all of the relevant HTML so we can reproduce your issue.

Comment: Shouldn't `let tr = $("<tr/>")` be `let tr = document.createElement('tr')`?

Comment: The input doesn't have a value so this arr.push($(this).val()); just fills the array with nohting

Comment: I don't get why you define the `populateArr()` and a click handler inside a `for` loop. Please check your code and look for missing curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this will work, I had a similar problem while using vanilla JavaScript.

When you append to the dom like below, you won't be able to add event listeners to the html tags.

```
$(tr).append("<input type='checkbox'/>").addClass("checkbox").val("val");
```

You should do this in your for loop when you filter for the `.checkbox` with attribute check it should work.

```
// convert code to jquery
let checkbox = document.createElement('checkbox');
check.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
checkbox.className = 'checkbox';
tr.appendChild(checkbox);
```

Comment: Elraphty, I improved your answer's formatting. Please, care about writing complete sentences, complete words (ex: your intead of ur) and include minimal punctuation. -- To have to code appear with a grey background, simply indent by four spaces.